# Neo4j - how to group and count by property?

Tags: neo4j

I have two node types in my Graph.
Node1 {id, name, node2id}
Node2 {id, name}

There are not relationships at this point, but I need to create between a:Node1 and b:Node2 only where Node2 are less than 100.

So, in SQL the query to get the nodes would be something like:

```
select Node1.Id, count(Node2.Id) as connections        
from Node1 left join Node2
    on (Node1.node2id = Node2.Id)
group by Node1.Id
having count(Node2.Id) < 100
```

How can I do this in Neo4J?
Ideally, I would like to add relationship between these Nodes, like

```
CREATE (n:Node1)-[:HAS_CONNECTION]->(k:Node2)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use something like:

```
MATCH (n1:Node1), (n2:Node2)
WHERE n1.node2id = n2Id
WITH n1, collect(n2) as nodes, count(*) AS count
WHERE count < 100
UNWIND nodes AS n
CREATE (n1)-[:HAS_CONNECTION]->(n)
```

You use the `WITH` statement to collect all the node2 that have the same id as node1, count them, and then apply a filter to them.

Comment: Thank you Tomaz, but it doesn't seem to work. It looks like count is ignored. I even tried count(n1) instead of *, but still it selects all the nodes. I am executing the part until "<100" with return n1, n to visualize the result before applying the relationships.
edit: also I noticed that "<" returns all the nodes, while ">" returns zero, whatever number I use after. Therefore I think "count(*)" doesn't really work

Comment: It is the other way around what I was looking for, but thank you for pointing me out to the correct direction. This is the correct query: MATCH (n1:Node1), (n2:Node2)
WHERE n1.node2Id = n2.Id
WITH collect(n1) as nodes, n2, count(n1) AS cnt
WHERE cnt < 100
UNWIND nodes AS n
CREATE (n)-[:HAS_CONNECTION]->(n2)